# Missing vc_runtimeminimum_x86.msi and installation won't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently going through the installation process for Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition to use with C++. Halfway through installation, I get an error stating

> "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable. Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package '**`vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi`**' in the box below."

If I hit cancel, the procedure continues and at the end tells me that the setup has failed. It gives me the error logs attached at the bottom of this post.

Also, I have uploaded the complete logs on the Microsoft Visual Studio developer help forum [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44676/missing-vc-runtimeminimum-x86msi-and-installation.html).

I'd like to be able to solve this problem without having to do a re-installation of the OS. So far, I've tried `/sfc scannow`, repairing through the Visual Studio Installer, and reinstalling the C++ redistributables, but all too no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

> `The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures. Incomplete workloads Desktop development with C++
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform development
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Visual Studio extension development
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Incomplete components C# and Visual Basic
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    C++ profiling tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    JavaScript and TypeScript language support
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Profiling tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Static analysis tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64)
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Visual Studio extension development prerequisites
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Visual Studio SDK
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VSSDK,version=15.0.26208.0) You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine. Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds. Package
>    'Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.10.25008,chip=x86' failed to install. Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1603 Impacted workloads Desktop development with C++
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform development
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Visual Studio extension development
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Impacted components C# and Visual Basic
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    C++ profiling tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    JavaScript and TypeScript language support
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Profiling tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Static analysis tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26403.0)
>    VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64)
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Visual Studio extension development prerequisites
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtension.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26208.0)
>    Visual Studio SDK
>    (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VSSDK,version=15.0.26208.0) Log
>    C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170412231725_117_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log
>    Details Command executed:
>    "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.10.25008,chip=x86\VC_redist.x86.exe" /q /norestart /log "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170412231725_117_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log"
>    Return code: 1603 Return code details: Fatal error during installation.`

Comment: Hi Khatrimm, have you installed the Visual C++ redistribute 2015 on your computer? If so, please try to uninstall it, run the tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed. After that, re-run the VS 2017 installer, right click the icon beside 'Launch' and choose 'Modify' or 'Repair'.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I uninstalled that and used that tool to fully cleanup and remove all of the 2015 C++ redistributables that showed up through that program (there were 4). Upon re-running the VS 2017 installer and repairing the installation, the program no longer occurred. Thank you so much!!! I've spent so much time trying to fix this problem, and now it's no longer occurring. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Khatrimm, I'm so glad to hear that my solution works for your issue. I added this workaround as reply, could you please mark it as answer, and it will help other community members to easier search this information :)

Comment: To get the install to work, I had to run this tool multiple times, in Uninstall mode, to uninstall all Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 entries in its list (e.g. Debug Runtime, Additional Runtime, Minimum Runtime). These entries did not appear in Programs and Features in Control Panel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Control Panel--Programs and Features, uninstall the Visual C++ 2015 Redistribute items.

After that, run the tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed. Re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator, then click the icon besides 'Launch' and choose 'Repair' to repair the VS 2017.

Comment: Downvoted, as you make zero mention of WHAT TO DO with this tool.  
Also, this tool seems kind of stupid. If you click "Install" (Which purports to help you tring to install something), it appears to show a list of *already* installed programs. Not sure how useful that is if the problem is that you cannot install it. I even tried running the tool WHILE the problem installer was running (As the problem VS version shows in add/remove programs at this point), but the tool still did not show it in the list.  
So as a tool to help you install a selected program, it seems utterly useless.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant the problem VC version shows in Add/Remove programs while it's installer is running and displaying the dialog.  
https://i.imgur.com/oYqbwRZ.png

Comment: Since the download link is dead, here are some working mirror links: http://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_program_install_and_uninstall_troubleshooter.html

Answer (score 31):

I ran into this problem as well on a recent build of Win 10 + trying to install latest VS Community. When I entered this state, things appeared to be super broken. Here's the sequence of events that I took which finally worked:

1. In the installed, select to "download all packages and then install"
2. Attempt installation
3. See the popup
4. With the popup still up, go here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed and download the tool
5. Open the tool and then select "Uninstall" on the page it says "do you need help installing or uninstalling"
6. On the next page with the list, select Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (whatever) and hit next to "Try Uninstall"
7. Repeat steps 5 - 6 until I didn't see any "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015" left in the list. Note that the popup is still showing.
8. Close the popup
9. Pause the install and Resume it.
10. I didn't see the pop up again and it appears to have installed correctly.

If you're coming here a year after the solution was marked without any resolution, try that and see if it works around the issue for you.

Here are some other things I tried which didn't work for me. If the above didn't work for you, maybe try some of the following which I collected through some searching:

- Going to C:\Program Data\Package Cache, searching for the msi package, giving the installer the literal path to what I found. Installer complains "wrong version"
- Using https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed after the install failed and then repairing (same error).
- Uninstalling VS 2015 packages after install failed and repairing (same error).
- Ignoring the error. When I did this, VS didn't have any templates installed and devenv /installvstemplates didn't solve this.

Comment: Thanks for detail steps. This worked for me in Win 7 when trying to install VS 2017

Comment: To others still coming here years later, Visual C++ redistributable files are shared for 2015, 2017, and 2019. You will need to clean up all three when installing 2019.

Comment: Thanks ! Works also for C++ 2015-2019 !

Comment: Work for me too. I had to remove all the Microsoft Visual C++ something as well.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my issue - Just removed all instances of Visual C++ 2015*

Comment: Jesus, that was rough - but this worked - thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This tool from Microsoft (which was mentioned by others here) worked for me, after I had been searching for an answer for days:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

You have to choose the "I have problems uninstalling" and search for your "C++"-components (in your case the 2017 ones).

There are usually the "Minimum runtime" and the "Additional runtime"-components. After I've uninstalled both of them with this tool, I could just install a programm that uses these runtimes (for example Visual Studio) and it would download and install the missing features, after that, everything workes perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing all the things from here: https://support.microsoft.com/ms-my/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Not sure if you just have to install the x86 version or all of them. recommend that you install all of them but remember to uninstall the ones which you already have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This can be SO painful. When using the Visual Studio Installer, look at the details of the component that can't be installed, e.g.
[image: Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 X86 Additional Runtime]

Then use the [Download troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) and choose to **Uninstall** the item mentioned. When hovering on the list of items, make sure the GUID shown matches the GUID in the error shown, e.g.
[image: Uninstall item from Download troubleshooter]

You might have to use Task Manager to force-stop Visual Studio Installer, but when run again, you should be able to complete your installation.

This issue isn't limited to VS2017CE - I've had exactly the same issue with VS2022Pro, which took about 4 hours to eventually install
[image: Visual Studio Professional 2022]

Answer (score -2):

for me was simple to fix this problem.

1. Uninstall all visual c++ with Revo Uninstaller Pro
2. Use MPVCI tool. link(https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/multipack_visual_c_installer.html)
3. enjoy it. for me it works.