# Visual Studio 2017 Community installation freeze on "Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017, failed-installation, visual-studio-community

I just installed *Windows 10 Fall Creator* and OS is completely updated.
I try to install "Visual Studio Community" now, but is frozen on ***Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14***.

I searched solutions, but nothing.
In my research, I understand that happens often.

- I have not installed antivirus yet.
- I have tried with the offline installation (I had downloaded and created the folder) by console: frozen.
- I have tried with the online installation: frozen.

Every suggestion is welcome.
TY

Comment: Try this answer, it should be same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537941/2164826

Comment: I've already tried, TY