# how to fix CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: Generator NMake Makefiles does not support platform specification, but platform x64 was specified

Tags: python, windows, cmake

I want to install dlib using *pip install dlib* using cmd in windows 10
But it is showing following three errors:
 CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

```
    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

INFORMATION:
pip 9.0.1 from d:\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
cmake 0.9.0
windows 10 pro(64-bit)
Version:  10.0.16299 Build 16299

Comment: Add by editing to your question version info of python, pip, cmake and win10: e.g.command-line: `pip -V` gives pip and python info.

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from d:\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
cmake 0.9.0
windows 10 pro(64-bit)
Version:  10.0.16299 Build 16299    please help me

Comment: @OwaseSayyed did you have ant luck in installing dlib on Win 10?
I have the same problem. 
Python 3.7, Win 10 (x64), pip 18, Anaconda 5.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am on windows 10, python 3.5, pip 10
dlib didn't work even after installing cmake.
Solution :

- Add cmake into PATH(C:\Program Files\CMake\bin)
- Then install using `pip`:

  ```
  pip install dlib==19.4
  ```

Works like a charm.

### Edit:

After windows October update, the above method works, but sometimes there are errors like `boost error` and `cmake incompatible`.
so,

- Download and install [CMake msi](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.3/cmake-3.14.3-win64-x64.msi)
- Add cmake into PATH(C:\Program Files\CMake\bin)
- Restart Windows
- ```
  pip install dlib
  ```

  or

  ```
  pip install dlib==19.4
  ```

Comment: Still getting 
" Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"

Answer (score 3):

First of all, delete CMakeCache.txt file. Later, just execute inside dlib-xx/build the command below:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
```

If you have more problems with CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, you will have to install MinGW and add to the enviroment variable the path /bin of MinGW.

And if you don't have installed Visual Studio, you would to resolve future problems

Comment: I am facing same problem. Cmake is getting executed when I am running command pip3 install face_recognition. I have installed MinGW. pip3 version is 9.03, Python 3.7 and cmake 3.12.0-rc3. It is still not resolved. I am struggling to find CMakeCache.txt.  Need help.

Comment: Where is `CMakeCache.txt` file

Comment: CMakeCache file can be found in the build folder

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem with you, and it has been solved after installing Visual Studio C++.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to install MS Visual Studio Community Edition, and select Visual C++ (install anything else you want but they are all optional except C++).
This will install CMake and the correct compiler and libs in the correct locations.

- Download the latest Dlib.
- CD into the Dlib folder.
- Make sure the Dlib/build folder is empty ( rm -r -force .\build* )
- Run: **python .\setup.py install**

If you get an error, post back here. You are probably missing a dependency or ENV variable.

Comment: If by "easiest" you mean downloading and installing 6-10GB… ¬_¬

Comment: @Synetech : The download is about 600 mb, the disk space required is approximately 5-6 GB. It worked for me and it's 'easiest' solution if don't want to find other work-around.,, Convenience vs. effort :-)

Comment: @MilindThakkar, What do convenience or effort have to do with it if the bandwidth and disk space are the limiting factor?

Comment: @Synetech I've never considered those to be a limiting factor in anything, which is why I posted it as easiest. I should have said "easiest for the user".

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem yesterday and looked up many resources. And at last I solved it by installing Visual Studio 2017, choosing C++-related component, because it needs the C++ compiler to build the dlib.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go this link [(dlib.whl)](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) and download .whl version of dlib and use this command to install it

```
pip install .\dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

but you should replace name of the file in above command with any file that you have downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Installing `dlib` from `.whl` worked.

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538054/9524424

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when installing `dlib` and `pqkmeans` Python packages.

1. Installing CMAKE or MinGW did not help.
2. I solved it only after installing the Build Tools for Visual Studio from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/) (so installing Visual Studion IDE, which is quite huge, is not necessary). When installing, I didn't check any additional ticks - the mininal proposed set of packages was enough.
3. When installing Visual Studio, I run into a problem from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512889/) (traces of older versions of VS) and dealt with it following the answers to this question.