# I'm not able to install dlib using pip command and manually both ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, dlib

I have been trying to download dlib on my system from past one week and I am not able to download it using pip or the manual process I also have looked on several questions asked here and checked the required processes like.

but still, I was unsuccessful ... I need to learn about opencv and dlib so please help me anyone ... and my device properties which I think might not be the problem.

Installed C and C++ compilers and add them to a path.

Installed visual studio 2015 (VS2015) down-loader and 2017 both

Installed all the dependencies through VS2015.(support for C, C++, MS Build, Windows SDK, etc)

```
C:\Users\Akshay>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc
78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\
python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\
\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qdv7218\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\
r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
 install --record 'C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dupqe8e6\instal
l-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:0
5) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-
8qdv7218\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Akshay\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qdv7218\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUT
ABLE=c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_L
IBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8
qdv7218\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Akshay/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8qdv7218/dlib/build
/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qdv7218\dlib\setup.p
y", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pack
ages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pack
ages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils
\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qdv7218\dlib\setup.p
y", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qdv7218\dlib\setup.p
y", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subproces
s.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppDat
a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qdv7218\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUT
PUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qdv7218\\dli
b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\akshay\\appdata\\l
ocal\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qdv7218\\dlib\\bu
ild\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\akshay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.e
xe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Akshay\\AppData\
\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qdv7218\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"
'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Us
ers\Akshay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dupqe8e6\install-record.txt' --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Akshay
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qdv7218\dlib\
```

Comment: Instead of the screenshot, paste into the question post the error log as a **text**. This is a **rule** of Stack Overflow. You may format the log pasted as a *code*, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: thank you Tsyvarev , I have made that change here ,please help me further

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624415/how-to-fix-cmake-error-in-cmakelists-txt-generator-nmake-makefiles-does-not-sup. (That is actually the same problem, but probably it lacks for working answer).

Comment: i have tried it and i am getting different set of  errors after this..