# Error in installing dlib refering to cmake

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip, dlib

So basically i want to use the Python face-recognition library and for that i have to install dlib. I am a windows user and while trying to install dlib i am getting this error

```
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Aayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Aayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-0jm25t0i' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Aayush/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-hvg3n3lr/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Aayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Aayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Aayush\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Aayush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvg3n3lr\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
```

Version details are as followed:

```
C:\Users\Aayush\facedet>pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from C:\Users\Aayush\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

I just want to install and use the face-recognition library with any way possible.

Comment: The error message "... does not support platform specification, but platform ... " is not new one. Have you checked other questions about it? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624415/how-to-fix-cmake-error-in-cmakelists-txt-generator-nmake-makefiles-does-not-sup. What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: ya i have checked them tried all the steps like installing a specific dlib version and others.. but no luck at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with face_recognition==0.2.2 version and its working with dlib==19.3.1

Hope this will help.

Comment: but i am also not able to install dlib 19.3.1 then how will it work

Comment: Download dlip ‘.wheel’ file as ur system requirement (use link below)
download link: https://pypi.python.org/simple/dlib/
Open cmd navigate to dlib wheel file path and hit command
“ pip install dlib_file_name.wheel”

Comment: ``` ERROR: dlib-19.3.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. ```