# Cmake error while trying to install openmesh for python

Tags: python, cmake, pip, installation, openmesh

I want to install openmesh for python. I've tried: pip install openmesh in the terminal in pycharm.
I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8. I've installed cmake using pip install cmake.

Now the following error occurs:

---

```
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
running install
running build
running build_ext

 Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
     Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know what to do?
I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48624415/3987854) have answers that help with your situation?