# Cannot install Visual Studio Correctly due to vc_runtimeminimum_x86.msi missing

Tags: c#, .net, installation

Essentially I was upgrading VS studio last night and had a power cut, any time I open VS studio I get "Assembly CSharp(failed to load)", I've tried everything in this thread

[Missing vc_runtimeminimum_x86.msi and installation won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512889/missing-vc-runtimeminimum-x86-msi-and-installation-wont-work)

I'm just a bit lost with what my solutions are as I need to use vs quite soon.
See image below for error i get whilst installing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrZu8.jpg