# Unable to install VS2019 software and throws 'Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14' error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to install the newest visual studio 2019 version (yes, I have a license for it). However, during the installation process the window freezes with this warning:

[image]

If I press cancel, it continues installation and completes with a warning.

After that, when I try to open VS2019, I get a create window with empty/blank project template:

[image: Create a new project window]

In addition, for every project a migration is required and afterwards there are problems with Nuget, as you can see here:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: '' is not a valid version string.
```

By migrating cs.proj to VS2019 it adds several fields like `OldToolsVersion, ToolsVersion` and stops working

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="Current">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="YYY" Version="1.0.0-CI-20200211-095627" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XXXX.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Resources\DataStructure.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In the end, I have a headache right now. I tried a lot - Reinstalling core, updating Nuget package.

[Missing vc_runtimeminimum_x86.msi and installation won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512889/missing-vc-runtimeminimum-x86-msi-and-installation-wont-work)

[NuGet Package Restore Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011889/nuget-package-restore-not-working)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you haven't already, try repairing the VS install from the VS installer. If it still has the same problem, [use the feedback tool within the installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019#step-4---report-a-problem) to report it directly to Microsoft. Stack Overflow is not a official support channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your error about restoring nuget has something to do with the issue of VS installation.

1.For `Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: '' is not a valid version string.` You can close VS, open `cmd.exe` => navigate to project folder where the `xx.csproj` exists and run command `dotnet restore` manually to restore packages for your project.

If the manual `dotnet restore` succeeds, then something wrong with VS IDE itself may cause the nuget restore issue. And if the `dotnet restore` command fails like in IDE, then i think there's something wrong with your project file itself. You should make sure you're using correct [package version format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning), and the specified package with specified version is available in [package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

2.For the vs installation error, just try [VS repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) like **zivkan** suggest. Also, if there's any windows update available, install it to check if it makes any help.

Comment: Hi @Lance Li-MSFT. I have tried `dotnet restore` command on cmd and it succeeded, also I can `dotnet run` with any erros. Regarding the VS repair I have tried multiple time to repair it, however everytime same thing happens -  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmJYE.png)

Comment: Ran VS Repair and installed latest windows updates.

Comment: Same result persists?

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned VS Repair and windows upgrade help to me. Thanks again