# Can't install MS Visual C++: "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable"

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, windows-10, dlib

"Installing MS Visual C++ : The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.

Click ok to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi' in the box below"

It gets a few percent in before this error comes up.

...
Part of larger issue - can't install dlib - in venv or outside. Was an issue before uninstalled C++, when it was installed fine (still got issue saying install C++ and cmake), so may share root cause?

```
(venv) D:\Programs\Prog Files General\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      <string>:125: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Building extension for Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jct_yn6\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jct_yn6\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\Programs\Prog Files General\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jct_yn6\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -A x64'
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


        You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
        are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
        that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
        development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\Programs\Prog Files General\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\Programs\Prog Files General\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "D:\Programs\Prog Files General\AI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 218, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1233, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1233, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1233, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wglxdb7s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 130, in run
        File "<string>", line 167, in build_extension
        File "C:\Users\ashbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\ashbu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jct_yn6\\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\ashbu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jct_yn6\\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=D:\\Programs\\Prog Files General\\AI\\stable-diffusion-webui\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\ashbu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jct_yn6\\dlib_8c9a3c866d204f87bc7cd41caf8a2345\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have cmake installed and used the add to path option.

Could this be a paths/evs issue, or perhaps related to the other windows 10 install I have on the physical drive (dual boot, partitioned)?

Have tried finding it in the installation folder but doesn't seem to be there.
Also tried changing the cache folder to a different folder/disk. And tried download first then install.
Also tried uninstalling .

Tried using the direct .exe installer, and get the pictured error.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512889/missing-vc-runtimeminimum-x86-msi-and-installation-wont-work)?